# Entity Framework error addobject Store update, insert, or delete statement affected an unexpected number of rows (0)

Tags: entity-framework, c#-4.0, entity-framework-4, dbcontext

I'm getting this error when I do an `AddObject` to my context. I've been looking around but most of the errors here are caused by changing the state to modified which is an update / attach function.

But I'm not trying to attach at all, I have online after declaring a new instance which is

```
Calendar calendar  = new Calendar { // stuff.... };

context.Calendars.AddObject(calendar);
context.SaveChanges();
```

that inserts the instance to the context. I tried adding the a change state line

```
context.ObjectStateManager.GetObjectStateEntry(calendar).ChangeState(System.Data.EntityState.Added);
```

But I still get the error.

Comment: what is the state of your object before you try to change the state?

Comment: it's added before the change. and even if i removed the extra line (changestate) it would still give me that error.

Comment: What does your Calendar object look like?